# Change UITextField behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uitextfield

What is the best way to disable UITextField's 'return' keyboard key if input area does not contain any text? `UITextField` with `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` property set to YES enables return key even if there are only spaces entered, but I'd like it to enable return key only when the text is not empty. any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to look into `UITextFieldDelegate` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you'd override the text input trait behaviour, but you could use the text field delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to prevent the user being able to enter spaces into an otherwise blank string. This would prevent any whitespace text being added, so the return key should not be enabled.

If you're not bothered about the return key actually being *enabled*, you could use `textFieldShouldReturn:`, again one of the text field delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following

1. Create an extension to String and add a trim method (it will become handy in other scenarios too that's why I suggest an extension.

   ```
   public func trim() -> String {
     return  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
   }
   ```
2. Make your class a delegate of UITextFieldDelegate and add the following fuction

   ```
   func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
     textField.text = textField.text.trim()
   }
   ```
3. Set the delegate of your UITextField to self.